# How many people you can feed with limited buget where some eat at a discount?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this logic problem I'm trying to code up for a game, and I think it might be more efficiently solved using linear algebra or some other mathematical method, but I'm so rusty I'm not sure where to look:

Say I have a limited budget of X dollars to feed Y people. The normal cost to feed each person is Z. However, I may also have any number of coupons that each entitles one person to eat at a discount, call it W - one coupon max per person.

For example,  I have 15 dollars, 20 people to feed, the normal cost to eat is 5 dollars, and I have 4 coupons that allow 4 of the people to eat for 2 dollars.

Note I may or may not have enough money to feed everyone, and I may or may not have any coupons, but whatever the case I want to feed the most people for the least possible price.

Is there a formula or set of them that will maximize the use of coupons and minimize the cost such that I can find out How many people get fed, the total cost, and how many coupons were used?

I've written the logic of this into C# and it works but it is gnarly and difficult to follow.  I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution!

Thanks for any advice that points me in the right direction!

Comment: Divide your budget $X$ by $W$, say you get $C$. $C$ is the max number of coupons you can use. If this number is more than the number of coupons you have (say $N$), then you can use all $N$ coupons. Now subtract $W \times N$ from your budget. Now see how many you can feed without coupon. If $C \leq N$, you can only feed $C$ people with coupons.

Comment: @Math Lover - thank you so much shaking the nuts loose in my head!  I am just dense sometimes.  Using your idea reduced my code by like %75.   It works!

Comment: You are welcome!